How to control AVAudioPlayer volume when AVAudioSession category is PlayAndRecord
I'm building an iOS app that only allows you to listen to audio through the builtInReceiver when the proximity sensor is activated, like so:
@interface CDVAudioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer
{
   NSString* mediaId;
}
----
self.avSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
audioFile.player = [[CDVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:resourceURL error:&playerError];
----
[self.avSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord mode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault options:0 error:&err];
[self.avSession setActive:true error:&err];
[self.avSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&err];

This works fine, except that when the proximity sensor is activated an the audio plays through the builtInReceiver the hardware volume buttons switch to in-call, thus having no effect on the AVAudioPlayer. Is there a way where I can let the in-call volume control the AVAudioPlayer?
